# $ionicScrollDelegate resize without using $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app in Ionic, and there are certain functions that load new sets of data into an existing view.

When I do this, sometimes if I have scrolled down, and the new data takes less space than the previous one, I am left with a blank screen until I scroll back up to where the new data is.

To prevent this, I am running an `$ionicScrollDelegate.resize();` which works, but it doesn't refresh. If I swipe (to reload data) twice, it resizes the view and bumps the scroll up if necessary, however if I do it just once, the scroll resizes, however does not bring the user up automatically. They have to start scrolling first, then it snaps them back to a scroll area that actually has data present.

I managed to solve this by using a watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.projects },
    function() {
        $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('taskScroll').resize();
    }
);
```

But I do not want to use a `$watch` for performance reasons. I've tried using various methods to get this resize to work from the event that calls the data to be reloaded, including `$apply`, `$evalAsync`, `$timeout`...

None of them worked, except `$timeout`, but then only when the interval was 500ms. This tells me it is an issue with the speed at which the data is loading and that is why `$watch` worked cause it keeps looking.

Is there anything else I can do to make the resize work immediately? This is the code for the event handler function:

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function () {

   var operatingDate = appContextService.getOperatingDate()
                                        .subtract(1,'days')
                                        .startOf('day');

   var pastDate = moment().subtract(1,'years')
                          .startOf('year')
                          .startOf('isoWeek');

    if (isSwipeEnabled && operatingDate.isAfter(pastDate)) {
        slideInCacheValidation(-1);
    }

    // Just one attempt at fixing this below, I've tried so many things that do not work...
    $scope.$eval( function() {
         $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('taskScroll').resize();
    });
};
```

Comment: Can't you call the resize event when the promise of getting the new data is resolved?

Comment: @thepio Yes! It worked! You all probably think I'm dumb for not trying it, but I did try it, was just advised to change some lines blah blah stuff, but when I just directly put it in the callback, disregarding what others asked me to do, it worked fine. Apologies, this isn't my field, I'm a designer by profession, I just had to do this due to a deadline and others having too much work.

Comment: nice to hear you got it working :) And no, I don't think your dumb, not in any situation :)